# Отправить POST в Angularjs по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc

Начал изучать angularjs. Приложение пишу на spring. Написал форму и поставил action на форму и на кнопку submit. Пока не было angularjs, то после отправки данных контроллер spring принимал данные и выдавал другую страницу. После применения angularjs не могу добиться, чтобы переходил на другую страницу, как и далее. Сам post в контроллер отправить получилось, но дальше глухо

Страница jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
    language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Регистрация пользователя</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding-bottom: 200;
}
</style>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:url value="/static/css/bootstrap.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<c:url value="/static/css/offcanvas.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link
    href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/static/js/bootstrap.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/static/js/maskedit.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/static/js/angularjs/angular.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            locale : 'ru',
            format : 'L'
        });
    });
    $(function($) {
        $("#datebirth").mask("99.99.9999");
    });
    var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);
    validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.submitForm = function() {
            if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
                alert($http==null);
                $http({
                    method : "POST",
                    url : "http://localhost:8080/App/regusr",

                })
            };
        };
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 align="center">Регистрация</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p align="center"><a href="<c:url value="/" />">На главную</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body" ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
                        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
                             <div class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.login.$invalid && !userForm.login.$pristine }">
                                    <label for="login" class="col-sm-4 control-label" style="padding-bottom: 5px">Логин</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Логин" ng-model="user.login" required>
                                        <p ng-show="userForm.login.$invalid && !userForm.login.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Пароль</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль" ng-model="user.password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="passwordConfirm" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Снова пароль</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" placeholder="Потверждение пароля" ng-model="user.passwordConfirm">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Полное имя</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Полное имя" ng-model="user.fullName">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 control-label">e-mail</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="e-mail" ng-model="user.email">
                                        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="datebirth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                                            <input type="date" id="datebirth" name="datebirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Дата рождения" ng-model="user.datebirth">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Зарегистрировать" 
                                            ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveEnterUser(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Успех! Пользователь зарегистрирован.");
        model.addAttribute("linkto", "/");
        model.addAttribute("title", "Регистрация пользователя");
        return "success";
    }
```

Можно как то сделать, чтобы валидация проходила, как я опишу через angularjs, а submit шёл, как и при обычной форме?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо вам надо не просто отправлять POST, но и обрабатывать ответ.

```
$http.post(
   'http://localhost:8080/App/regusr', 
   JSON.stringify(data)
).success(function(){/*success callback*/});
```

Тут более подробно:
http://jsfiddle.net/YGQT9/

PS. Вы пытаетесь смешать два разных подхода для построения UI. Это и приводит к тому, что у вас что-то перестаёт работать. Лучше использовать либо только AngularJS, либо только JSP(+чистый JS или jQuery).